# Reshaping the columns into rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Q
45
21
32
45
54
65
78
55
56
546
55
566
56
566
581
55
```

i need to transform this particular column into :

```
Q   A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7  A8  A9  A10 A11 A12
45  21  32  45  54  65  78  55  56  546 55  566 56
21  32  45  54  65  78  55  56  546 55  566 56  566
32  45  54  65  78  55  56  546 55  566 56  566 581
45  54  65  78  55  56  546 55  566 56  566 581 55
54  65  78  55  56  546 55  566 56  566 581 55  0
65  78  55  56  546 55  566 56  566 581 55  0   0
78  55  56  546 55  566 56  566 581 55  0   0   0
55  56  546 55  566 56  566 581 55  0   0   0   0
56  546 55  566 56  566 581 55  0   0   0   0   0
546 55  566 56  566 581 55  0   0   0   0   0   0
55  566 56  566 581 55  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
566 56  566 581 55  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
56  566 581 55  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
566 581 55  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
581 55  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
55  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

this dataframe.
As i also tried shift i am not able to Acheive the output.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please provide a description of what you have tried and what went wrong?

Comment: @jai This Question is the part of my earlier Question in which I mention everything which required to understand my approach to this question.

Comment: How working solution?

Comment: @jezreal its working fine .but i have an another issue if u help me or suggest some 
solution . Actually i created a path like path_file=user/abc/rnd_ghm_[0-9]*.      But when i try to create dataframe then simply.          data=pd.read_csv(path_file,sep='|',engine='python')        but it throw me that path does not exist. My actual file is something like user/abc/rnd_ghm09754747.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with created new columns in `for` loop:

```
for i in range(1, 13):
    df[f'A{i}'] = df['Q'].shift(-i, fill_value=0)

print (df)
      Q   A1   A2   A3   A4   A5   A6   A7   A8   A9  A10  A11  A12
0    45   21   32   45   54   65   78   55   56  546   55  566   56
1    21   32   45   54   65   78   55   56  546   55  566   56  566
2    32   45   54   65   78   55   56  546   55  566   56  566  581
3    45   54   65   78   55   56  546   55  566   56  566  581   55
4    54   65   78   55   56  546   55  566   56  566  581   55    0
5    65   78   55   56  546   55  566   56  566  581   55    0    0
6    78   55   56  546   55  566   56  566  581   55    0    0    0
7    55   56  546   55  566   56  566  581   55    0    0    0    0
8    56  546   55  566   56  566  581   55    0    0    0    0    0
9   546   55  566   56  566  581   55    0    0    0    0    0    0
10   55  566   56  566  581   55    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
11  566   56  566  581   55    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
12   56  566  581   55    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
13  566  581   55    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
14  581   55    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
15   55    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

For second sample data:

```
for i in range(1, 13):
    df[f'A{i}'] = df['Q'].shift(-i, fill_value=0)
print (df)
    Q  A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7  A8  A9  A10  A11  A12
0  45  21  32  45  54  65  57   0   0   0    0    0    0
1  21  32  45  54  65  57   0   0   0   0    0    0    0
2  32  45  54  65  57   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0
3  45  54  65  57   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0
4  54  65  57   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0
5  65  57   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0
6  57   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0
```

---

If need all columns:

```
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df[f'A{i}'] = df['Q'].shift(-i, fill_value=0)
```

Comment: its for part one not for 2nd part

Comment: @Sudhakar - Answer was edited, can you be more specific? Some error? Because for me working nice.